# Is it possible to run SpringFox' swagger and swagger-ui on a different port than the main application?

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui

We are using SpringBoot and SpringFox using `@EnableSwagger2` to expose the `swagger-ui.html` API documentation (we don't need it to automate client code, just as documentation and test ui).

Is it possible to run all swagger related endpoints under a different port (for example the spring boot management/monitoring port) than the main application?

I researched a bit, but did not find a way in swagger's/springfox' configuration to do it. Is there a spring way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, there is a Spring way of doing this:

### Step 1. Adding an additional Tomcat connector

To add a port to the embedded server an additional connector needs to be configured.
We will do it by providing custom WebServerFactoryCustomizer:

```java
@Component
public class TomcatContainerCustomizer implements WebServerFactoryCustomizer<TomcatServletWebServerFactory> {

    @Value("${swagger.port}")
    private int swaggerPort;

    @Override
    public void customize(TomcatServletWebServerFactory factory) {

        Connector swaggerConnector = new Connector();
        swaggerConnector.setPort(swaggerPort);
        factory.addAdditionalTomcatConnectors(swaggerConnector);
    }
}
```

Now Tomcat listens on two ports but it serves the same content on both of them. We need to filter it.

### Step 2. Adding a filter

Adding a servlet filter is pretty straightforward with a FilterRegistrationBean.
It can be created anywhere, I added it directly to the TomcatContainerCustomizer.

```java
@Component
public class TomcatContainerCustomizer  implements WebServerFactoryCustomizer<TomcatServletWebServerFactory> {

    @Value("${swagger.port}")
    private int swaggerPort;

    @Value("${swagger.paths}")
    private List<String> swaggerPaths;

    @Override
    public void customize(TomcatServletWebServerFactory factory) {

        Connector swaggerConnector = new Connector();
        swaggerConnector.setPort(swaggerPort);
        factory.addAdditionalTomcatConnectors(swaggerConnector);
    }

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean<SwaggerFilter> swaggerFilterRegistrationBean() {

        FilterRegistrationBean<SwaggerFilter> filterRegistrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean<>();
        filterRegistrationBean.setFilter(new SwaggerFilter());
        filterRegistrationBean.setOrder(-100);
        filterRegistrationBean.setName("SwaggerFilter");

        return filterRegistrationBean;
    }

    private class SwaggerFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

        private AntPathMatcher pathMatcher = new AntPathMatcher();

        @Override
        protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest,
                                        HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse,
                                        FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {

            boolean isSwaggerPath = swaggerPaths.stream()
                    .anyMatch(path -> pathMatcher.match(path, httpServletRequest.getServletPath()));
            boolean isSwaggerPort = httpServletRequest.getLocalPort() == swaggerPort;

            if(isSwaggerPath == isSwaggerPort) {
                filterChain.doFilter(httpServletRequest, httpServletResponse);
            } else {
                httpServletResponse.sendError(404);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The properties `swagger.port` and `swagger.paths` are configured in the application.yaml:

```
server.port: 8080
swagger:
  port: 8088
  paths: |
    /swagger-ui.html,
    /webjars/springfox-swagger-ui/**/*,
    /swagger-resources,
    /swagger-resources/**/*,
    /v2/api-docs
```

So far so good: the swagger-ui is served on the port 8088, our api on the 8080.
But there is a problem: when we try to connect to the api from the swagger-ui,
the requests are sent to the 8088 instead of 8080.

### Step 3. Adjusting SpringFox config.

Swagger assumes that the api runs on the same port as the swagger-ui.
We need to explicitly specify the port:

```java
@Value("${server.port}")
private int serverPort;

@Bean
public Docket docket() {
    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
            .host("localhost:" + serverPort);
}
```

And the last problem: as the ui runs on a different port than the api,
the requests are considered cross-origin. We need to unblock them.
It can be done globally:

```java
@Bean
public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
    return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
        @Override
        public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
            registry.addMapping("/**/*").allowedOrigins("http://localhost:" + swaggerPort);
        }
    };
}
```

or by adding annotations to the controllers:

```java
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:${swagger.port}")
```

Versions used: SpringBoot 2.2.2.RELEASE, springfox-swagger2 2.9.2

For a working example see https://github.com/mafor/swagger-ui-port

Comment: The WebServerFactoryCustomizer was the missing point! This looks very promising, thanks very much for the time you spent! Will try it following exactly those steps.

Comment: Is it possible to run two instances of swagger on two different ports like 8080 and 8088? I want to use swagger-ui on port 8080 to show public URLs and swagger-ui on port 8088 to show internal URLs.

Comment: I am getting this -
Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:8080/myapi' from origin 'http://localhost:8099' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'http://localhost:8080' that is not equal to the supplied origin. Have the server send the header with a valid value, or, if an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled. 

Have configured corsConfigurer also as specified. Still facing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so. When you're setting the Spring Boot management port (management.server.port), a second application server gets started to serve the actuator stuff. As far as I know there is no possibility (apart from custom actuator endpoints) to publish something on that server.
What is your use case exactly? Do you want to prevent access to Swagger in production or for non-authenticated users?

Comment: Yes, correct. I have already an option for authenticated users. But what we want to do is publish it under a different port. So that the API itself can be exposed worldwide while the rest (management, swagger -- as there is internal documentation included), is still hidden or only reachable internally.